# Pandas dataframe: how to create multiple groups with combinations of rows

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

```
         a       b       c       d
0    Apple   Apple   Apple  Banana
1    Apple   Apple  Banana   Apple
2    Apple   Apple  Banana  Banana
3    Apple  Banana  Banana  Banana
4    Apple  Banana  Banana    Pear
5    Apple  Banana    Pear   Apple
6    Apple    Pear   Apple   Apple
7    Apple    Pear  Banana   Apple
8    Apple    Pear  Banana  Banana
9   Banana  Banana    Pear  Banana
10  Banana  Banana    Pear    Pear
11  Banana    Pear  Banana   Apple
12  Banana    Pear  Banana  Banana
13    Pear   Apple  Banana  Banana
14    Pear  Banana  Banana   Apple
15    Pear  Banana    Pear    Pear
16    Pear    Pear   Apple    Pear
17    Pear    Pear  Banana   Apple
18    Pear    Pear  Banana  Banana
```

Hello,

I have the following dataframe df.
I would like to create a new dataframe containing groups of rows that has twice the value "Apple" or another group having rows with twice the value of "Banana"or one group containing only Banana once in a row etc. I would like to create a limited number of groups, let says just 6 that has those different combinations.
I though of using group.by but I am not sure how to use it while extracting values. Any help? Thank you!

Comment: [Avoid post image as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15239951). Can your export your dataframe as text: `print(df.to_string(index=False)` for example, please? And show us what do you expect as result?

Comment: I will put above the table expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can first create a Series that contains the value count of specific value in row. Then filter that Series by the value count you want.

Following is an example creating a new dataframe containing rows that has twice the value "Apple".

```py
apple_count = df.apply(lambda row: row.isin(['Apple']).sum(axis=0), axis=1)

df_ = df[apple_count.isin([2, 4])]
```

```
print(df_)

       a       b       c       d
2  Apple   Apple  Banana  Banana
5  Apple  Banana    Pear   Apple
7  Apple    Pear  Banana   Apple
```

Comment: Thank you! I think that will do!! Is the index on the left the number of rows having Apple Apple Banana Banana for the first line?

Comment: @JessBR Don't quite understand what you are saying. Index is the number in the left of your pic, `0,1,2,3..`.

Comment: Alright! Thank you for your precious help!

Comment: @JessBR To achieve what you want in your pic, you only need to call `apple_count.value_counts()` to get the count of `Apple` in each row.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This great learning from your help!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Ideally I would like something like this, sorry it should be group 1, 2, 3 etc but since my initial df is quiet long in rows I want a limited number of groups, maybe 10 to plot after.
Group 1 will have all rows where variables are in pairs, group 2 could gave all rows where variables are seem 3 times, group 4 could have all rows where one variable is seen only once in each column for the same row etc.
What I would like at the end is to plot the frequencies of those groups.

Answer (score 0):

To make groups

```py
def count_words(values, word):
    return sum([value == word for value in values])

apple_groups = df.groupby(by=lambda index: count_words(df.loc[index], 'Apple'))

for word_count, group in apple_groups:
    print(group)
```

```
         a       b       c       d
9   Banana  Banana    Pear  Banana
10  Banana  Banana    Pear    Pear
12  Banana    Pear  Banana  Banana
15    Pear  Banana    Pear    Pear
18    Pear    Pear  Banana  Banana

         a       b       c       d
3    Apple  Banana  Banana  Banana
4    Apple  Banana  Banana    Pear
8    Apple    Pear  Banana  Banana
11  Banana    Pear  Banana   Apple
13    Pear   Apple  Banana  Banana
14    Pear  Banana  Banana   Apple
16    Pear    Pear   Apple    Pear
17    Pear    Pear  Banana   Apple

       a       b       c       d
2  Apple   Apple  Banana  Banana
5  Apple  Banana    Pear   Apple
7  Apple    Pear  Banana   Apple

       a      b       c       d
0  Apple  Apple   Apple  Banana
1  Apple  Apple  Banana   Apple
6  Apple   Pear   Apple   Apple
```

To count in groups

```py
def count_rows_with_exactly_n_words(df, word, n):
    return df.apply(lambda row: count_words(row.values, word) == n, axis=1).sum()

def count_word_groups(df, word, max_n):
    result = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Count'])
    for n in range(max_n + 1):
        result.at[word + '_' + str(n), 'Count'] = count_rows_with_exactly_n_words(df, word, n)
    return result

print(count_word_groups(df, 'Apple', max_n=4))
print(count_word_groups(df, 'Banana', max_n=4))
```

```
        Count
Apple_0     5
Apple_1     8
Apple_2     3
Apple_3     3
Apple_4     0

         Count
Banana_0     2
Banana_1     6
Banana_2     8
Banana_3     3
Banana_4     0
```